# How to set default time on Bootstrap timepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, timepicker

How can I set default time instead of current time for this datetimepicker http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can set the default time via JavaScript :

```
$('mySelector').timepicker({defaultTime: '10:45 PM'});
```

Or directly via the value attribute of your timepicker :

```
<div class="bootstrap-timepicker">
    <input id="timepicker" type="text" value="10:45 AM"/>
</div>

$('.myClass').timepicker({defaultTime: 'value'});
```

EDIT : was for the default timepicker of boostrap, my bad.

For your specific timepicker, it seems possible to set the datetime like this :

```
var picker = $('#datetimepicker').data('datetimepicker');
picker.setDate(myDate);
```

Answer (score 5):

**From the documentation page.**.

setTime Set the time manually

```
  $('#timepicker').timepicker('setTime', '12:45 AM');
```

Answer (score 0):

For bootstrap timepicker this would work :

```
$('selector').val("time");
```

Answer (score 0):

I Think You Should try this. It work for me

```
$('.time').timepicker({
    minuteStep: 1,
    defaultTime: null
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Set value before to initialize timepicker

```
$('#start_time').val('12:00 AM');
$('#start_time').timepicker();
```

Might be working this way